# Is a monster's stats static, or is it based on some random value?

Tags: diablo-iii

I wasn't really paying attention until last night when I started Inferno, and I noticed the zombies outside of town had health that ranged from 60,000 to 85,000, with no two hp bars being the same amount (based on about 20 zombies)

This got me wondering, is a monster's stats randomized within a range based on level?

Comment: How do you see hp number for enemies, or do you count the damage done?

Comment: @Alok: I'm pretty sure it's in the options.

Comment: Are the "zombies" you refer to all the exact same type?  "Risen" I'm assuming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you realized it yourself, they are indeed randomized, just like in Diablo 2.

For detailed stats, check this out: http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Diablo_III_Monsters. Not all of them have stats filled up yet, but you can check this one as an example: http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Accursed